# Run command after file manager (Thunar) window is closed

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal, thunar

I am writing a simple script where I need to open a directory `dirname` with Thunar and delete that directory after closing the Thunar window.
I was expecting something like

```bsh
thunar $dirname && rm -r $dirname
```

to work.

The issue is that the `thunar` process does not seem to stay connected to the terminal after starting up: after running `thunar $dirname`, the shell goes directly to the next command, instead of waiting the `thunar` window to be closed. How can I work around this?

Comment: @sudodus The only process I see involving thunar is the thunar --daemon process, which is not specific for this window

Comment: I'm running your script and the directory is removed *after* thunar is closed. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

There's a Thunar process already running with "--daemon" option so that any new Thunar invocation will use this one and your try to start a new Thunar process fails and rm immediately runs. Note that "Thunar --daemon" itself does *not* open a Thunar window.

The daemon process is usually started at login by definition in /etc/xdg/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-session.xml ("/etc", not "~"). Removing the "--daemon" flag there will impact existing scripts that not expect to wait for Thunar to be closed, and it will block your command line if you start Thunar from there.

You can "kill" the Thunar daemon before your relevant script line with `Thunar -q`, run the line, and restart the daemon with `Thunar --daemon &` after it - be aware of the `&` at the end to start the daemon in the background, otherwise your script waits for it to end). **Caveat:** all Thunar windows that were open "on" the Thunar daemon you "killed" will disappear without notice.

So your full line might be

```
Thunar -q && thunar $dirname && rm -r $dirname && Thunar --daemon &
```

You might take a look at [Thunar's manpage](https://www.mankier.com/1/Thunar)

Answer (score 0):

When there is already a Thunar process running (desktop manager or another window), a new Thunar window will be detached from the calling process and the next command will be started, and there is no `pid` for a particular window. This is well described in the answer by hh skladby.

I want to solve the problem without turning off the already started Thunar process.

It seems difficult to use the `pid` [alone], but there is a `wid` (Window ID), that can be found via `wmctrl -lp` (in combination with some smart logic). Let the shellscript check for it (repeatedly in a loop) and when the `wid` is gone you can remove the directory.

The following shellscript shows how it can be done. It is only a demo script, because there is no other action but solving the problem specified in the question.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "" ]
then
 echo "No directory on command line"
 dirname="MyDir"
else
 dirname="$1"
fi
mkdir -p "$dirname"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
 echo "Bad directory name, try again"
 exit 1
fi

thunar "$dirname"

pid=$(ps -e | grep -i thunar | sed -e 's/ *//' -e 's/ .*//')
#echo "$pid"
sleep 1
wid=$(wmctrl -lp | grep " $pid " | grep "${dirname##*/}" | tail -n1)
wid=$(echo "$wid" | tee /dev/stderr | sed 's/ .*//')
#echo "$wid"
echo "Waiting for you to close the Thunar window '${dirname##*/}' ..."
while wmctrl -lp | grep "$wid" > /dev/null
do
 sleep 1
done
rm -r "$dirname"
echo "Done :-)"
```